# Listbox : listboxitem with group and without group listboxitem

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

So I am using list box as a side navigation bar

I am trying to sort my listbox from this

- Listboxitem 1 (Home)
- Listboxitem 2 (Log out)
- Group with expander (Accounting) with listboxitems children(Sales, Product)

to this :

- Listboxitem 1 (Home)
- Group with expander (Accounting) with listboxitems children(Sales, Product)
- Listboxitem 2 (Log out)

but I cant seem to sort the 3 items based on their index in itemsource.

[Basically this is listbox I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAYEZ.png)

This is how I added the items in my listbox

```
public ObservableCollection<ContentObject> ContentItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ContentObject>();
public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ChangeToggleStateCommand = new RelayCommand(action => { IsMenuToggleEnabled = false;});

        ContentItems.Add(new ContentObject("Home", new HomeView(), MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.PackIconKind.Home,"None"));
        ContentItems.Add(new ContentObject("Sales", new SalesView(), MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.PackIconKind.CashMultiple, "Accounting"));
        ContentItems.Add(new ContentObject("Product", new ProductsView(), MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.PackIconKind.CubeOutline, "Accounting"));
        ContentItems.Add(new ContentObject("Log out", new SalesView(), MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.PackIconKind.Logout, "None"));
    }
```

The list box XAML CODE

```
<ListBox x:Name="ContentList" Margin="0 16 0 16" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListBoxItems}}" >
                        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate>
                                                    <Expander IsExpanded="False">
                                                        <Expander.Header>
                                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                <TextBlock FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Name}"  Margin="15 15" />
                                                            </StackPanel>
                                                        </Expander.Header>
                                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                                    </Expander>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="None">
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                                            <StackPanel>
                                                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                                                            </StackPanel>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            </GroupStyle>
                        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border BorderThickness="0">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding Icon}" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="15 15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <TextBlock FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Title}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChangeToggleStateCommand}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </ListBox>
```

Here's how I grouped my ContentItems

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ListBoxItems" Source="{Binding Path=ContentItems,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Category"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
```

Based on  the way I implemented it. the default template is tagged to category :None
.Wpf is assuming that none is also a group containing Home and Logout thus the treating it as a group without a header. that is why I am not able to separate the two listboxitems. Is there another way to separate this or implement this?

I found a similar question but sorting was not addressed

[WPF Listbox grouping, items with no groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878270/wpf-listbox-grouping-items-with-no-groups)

Test the code here : https://github.com/asdtgb/NavigatorTest